# Adding a class to a div not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am dynamically creating a div using jQuery and then adding a class to it in order to style it:

```
var borderDiv = $('<div />').addClass('borderTaco');
// add borderDiv to the DOM...
```

Where borderTaco is defined to be the following style:

```
.borderTaco {
  background-color : #cde;
  z-index : 1;
  height : 100%;
}
```

Even though the element is being properly inserted into the DOM, the style doesn't seem to be applied to the div. When I inspect the element in firebug, it indicates that the element does have the correct class attribute, but it has no style rules and doesn't appear correctly.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/acuko3/2) is a jsbin of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is used in an iframe so the class should be defined in this iframe.

Comment: Your next question being: how do I define a class in an iframe? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `addClass` after the div is added to the DOM.

```
var borderDiv = $('<div />');
// add to DOM
borderDiv.addClass('borderTaco');
```

Comment: Is this behavior intermittent, or is there a difference between divs and iframes? Note that in the jsbin in the question, I'm doing the same thing with an iframe, but it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add the class right to the div in the selector:

```
$('<div class="borderTaco" />').appendTo('body');
```